# SED find and replace internal filepaths from files

Tags: sed, regular-expression

we have few asset files with internal filepaths, for example `"/Users/testuser/dev/app-path/widget"` such as below.

**test.js**

```
[["elliptic@6.5.2","/Users/testuser/dev/app-path/widget"]],"_development":true,
"_where":"/Users/testuser/dev/app-path/widget","author"
```

I am looking for `SED` to replace all internal filepaths with **blank/empty** string. When I do `grep` as below my *regex* works

```
grep -E '"/Users\/.*?"' ./resources/test.js
```

But, when I try to use regex `SED` as below, my file's filepath is *NOT* getting replaced with blank string, not sure what I'm missing. Please suggest.

```
find ./resources -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/"\/Users\/.*?"/""/g' {} \;
```

[image: SED example]

I have tried looking at other similar posts but could not find anything relevant to replace `"/Users/testuser/dev/app-path/widget"` --> `""`

regex works on **Regex101** : https://regex101.com/r/YycQkX/2/

Comment: Your regular expression is a PCRE. `sed` understand POSIX regular expressions. Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Comment: how does `grep` work, does it support PCRE ?

Comment: It does not work. You could try to see what bits are matched with `grep -o -E ...` and you'll notice that you match much more than the pathname.  Also, you require GNU `grep` which is more lenient about its patterns.  BSD `grep` will complain with `repetition-operator operand invalid`.  GNU `grep` also supports PCRE, but with its `-P` option.

Comment: Testing that a regexp works on regex101.com proves that that regexp works on regex101.com. It doesn't mean it'll work in any other tool, especially standard UNIX tools. If you want to create a regexp that works in sed then you need to learn the syntax, caveats, extensions, options, etc. of whatever sed variant you are planning to use. And then don't assume that the regexp you come up with for that sed command will work in grep or awk or.... - they're all different from each other to varying degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace `"/Users/testuser/dev/app-path/widget"` with `""` in your files, you could use a POSIX Basic Regular Expression (BRE):

```
find ./resources -type f -exec sed -i 's/"\/Users\/[^"]*"/""/g' {} +
```

The `[^"]*` part matches any sequence of non-`"` characters.

**Edit:**
You could also use a different delimiter in the substitution to prevent escaping of the slashes (thanks [@Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569467/sed-find-and-replace-internal-filepaths-from-files/569478?noredirect=1#comment1059151_569478)), e.g. using a `:` instead of the `/`:

```
find ./resources -type f -exec sed -i 's:"/Users/[^"]*":"":g' {} +
```

Comment: thanks Freddy and @Kusalananda